# Is the following property for positive random variables fulfilled in general?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, conditional-expectation, probability-inequalities

[I have cross-posted this from math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476466/is-the-following-property-for-positive-random-variables-fulfilled-in-general ]

Suppose we have a continuous random variable $X$, defined on the interval $[0, \infty)$, which has density $f(x)$ and a finite expectation and variance.

I am wondering whether the following is true in general:

Take any value $\alpha > 0$, and let

$x_1 := \mathbb{E}(X|X \leq \alpha)$, while

$x_2 := \mathbb{E}(X|X > \alpha)$.

Will a new, discrete random variable $\tilde{X}$, where
$\tilde{X} = x_1$ with probability $F(\alpha)$, and $\tilde{X} = x_2$ with probability $1-F(\alpha)$, always have a lower variance than $X$?

I have checked that this property is true for the uniform distribution. Formally, it is straightforward to see that the property is fulfilled if for all $\alpha > 0$,

$\int_{0}^{\infty} x^2 f(x)dx \geq \frac{\left(\int_0^\alpha x f(x) dx\right)^2}{F(\alpha)} + \frac{\left(\int_\alpha^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2}{1-F(\alpha)}$.

Using Jensen's inequality, a sufficient condition for the above is that

$\left(\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x)dx\right)^2 \geq \frac{\left(\int_0^\alpha x f(x) dx\right)^2}{F(\alpha)} + \frac{\left(\int_\alpha^\infty f(x) dx\right)^2}{1-F(\alpha)}$.

However, I am not really sure where to go from there. The integral in the LHS can still be split up into the range $0$ to $\alpha$ and $\alpha$ to $\infty$, but doesn't seem to help me much.

Maybe the property is not true in general, after all?

Any input is appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you not satisfied with Did answer?, if not what different you want?. It seems same question and already answered.

Comment: I guess I am. Note that I made this cross-post short *before* Did provided his detailed answer.

Comment: That answer was fine in terms of the algorithmic approach, but a better probability approach, hinted at by @Azeem, is to use the concept of conditional expectations. I personally would think that this is a better thing to do than to manipulate some integrals, so I would encourage Azeem to write it up. In general, Martin, questions should be *migrated*, not *cross-posted* -- the latter creates confusion, as it just did, while the former follows the workflow.

Comment: @StasK: Agreed, but OP already accept the answer at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: The intuitive answer is "of course it's true," because variation is reduced when collapsing the two intervals of values into their expectations. We would therefore expect that an ANOVA-like calculation that decomposes the variance of $X$ into variances of its two truncated versions plus some term depending on the square of the difference of the expectations would succeed. This leads me to suspect a proof can be found that reduces to demonstrating that the square of something is non-negative :-). (Ultimately that's how the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality [used in the cross post] is proven anyway.)

Comment: The proof is easy if you use the alternate definition of variance, half the expected squared difference between two independent observations, and consider what you get when both observations are on the same side of *a* and on different sides of *a*.